# lightswitch room booking application

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have the following tables:

```
rooms table       contains  Room_Number   INT  PK
res_appointment   contains  Id            INT  PK
                            Room_Number   INT
                            Start_Date    DATE
                            End_Date      DATE
```

I want to build a query with parameters   Check In Date( Start Date) and Check Out date ( End Date)
I want the query to select only room number from Rooms Table where has records in in res_appointment table between the parameters Check In Date  & Check Out Date

in summery i need to list only rooms that is busy in the date range between Check In Date and Check Out Date Parameters .

Is there any method to do that in VB lightswitch

Answer (score 0):

Create a Relationship or Foreign Key between the two tables on the Room_Number. Then use the Query designer to Filter the table to return the results in the specified date range. Once the two tables are linked, you can access the rooms_table from the Query.